# GitHub - Pushed a change to master, but appears as different user than me?

Tags: git, bash, github

I have a GitHub repo located [here](https://github.com/KevinTyrrell/FishingBot). I just commited a change to my repo and pushed to `master` branch, as I always do. I entered my account name and password, and the commit was pushed to GitHub. However, when I checked my [GitHub commits page](https://github.com/KevinTyrrell/FishingBot/commits/master), I see a [user that is **not me**](https://github.com/0).

Did I do something wrong? I'm on a new computer that just installed `Git Bash`. I usually use `Git Bash` on my laptop. Was I supposed to somehow identify myself on my `Git Bash` client before using repos? I'm so confused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is more clearly seen if you look at the [raw commit](https://github.com/KevinTyrrell/FishingBot/commit/7a3502a69763791d6ebd54b54fab370a181c91e5.patch), which can be done by adding `.patch` to the normal commit URL. It shows this line:

`From: User <User>`

So it looks like some generic defaults got picked up. You may have entered your username and password as *Github credentials* which are separate from your identity that goes into your commit.

Follow the [official Github instructions](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-your-email-in-git/) for setting your name and email address, which boils down to this command to set it globally:

```
git config --global user.email "your_email@example.com"
```

And this command for the local repo:

```
git config user.email "your_email@example.com"
```

Comment: Thank you. I forgot I needed to do whenever I install `Git`.  How do I now revert the repo so that random user isn't shown, then re-commit it?

Comment: Try searching for the answer. If not found, Ask a new StackOverflow question.